# What is prefered method to put footnotes for html table?

Tags: xhtml, html-table, accessibility, semantic-markup

Like this; this a screenshot of MS word file.

[image]

- Should I put in a `tfoot` or in `td`
  as a `<p>dwdwdewwe</p>` or  should I
  put after `</table>` in a `<p></p>`?
- and can we put `tfoot` anywhere
  inside `<table>`
- And should I give link to footnotes *
  to jum to footnotes at bottom.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `tfoot` tag.  It must appear before the `tbody` tag.  See also: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.3

```
<table>
    <thead><tr><td colspan="5">This is the header and should span all columns.</td></tr></thead>
    <tfoot><tr><td colspan="5">This is the footer and should span all columns.</td></tr></tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>11</td><td>12</td><td>13</td><td>14</td><td>15</td>
        <tr><td>21</td><td>22</td><td>23</td><td>24</td><td>25</td>
        <tr><td>31</td><td>32</td><td>33</td><td>34</td><td>35</td>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: ok it's `tfoot` so i was thinking it will come after `</tbody>`

Comment: It is displayed after the `tbody` by the browser, even though it appears before `tbody` in the markup.

Comment: and should i use <ol> <li> inside <tfoot> in footnotes are like this [1], [2]

Answer (score 3):

I think you should use the `tfoot` tag, since it's semnatically designated for this type of stuff. But, like many things in HTML, you aren't forced to do it *one way or another* - you've got some liberty.

This particular example would suffice either way - as a simple `TR` containing a `TD` (with a colspan if necessary), or a `TFOOT` with a `TD` (with a collspan if necessary).

As far as adding links within the body to jump to the footer, it's awfully nice from a usability standpoint. But that type of thing isn't objectively answerable - it depends on what your project requiremens are.

You can't put a `TFOOT` just *anywhere* within a table, ther are rules (`<td><tfoot>...</tfoot></td>` would be a no-no). For proper use of the `TFOOT` tag, consult http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_tfoot.asp

Comment: So stick to the books. Keep your markup semantically-correct and simple. View the w3schools link for a great example of how to properly use the `tfoot` tag. Good luck! :)